# Angular 7 - ngTemplateOutlet Variable Value (Expression)

Tags: angular, ng-container

I am unable to pass the value of *ngTemplateOutlet in my ng-container via a variable.

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent  {
  templateName="SingleSelect";
}
```

app.component.html

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="{{templateName}}">

</ng-container>

<ng-template #SingleSelect>
<p>Output from test template</p>
</ng-template>

{{templateName}}
```

Of course if I define below, everything works as expected

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="SingleSelect">

</ng-container>
```

How can I make SingleSelect a variable value?

Stackblitz for reference- 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h4mgyq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such a use case, you first have to capture the defined template via a [ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) query which luckily also supports **[TemplateRef](https://angular.io/api/core/TemplateRef)**.

Excerpt from [angular.io](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild#description)

> ### ViewChild
>
> Property decorator that configures a view query.
>
> The following selectors are supported.
>
> - ...
> - A TemplateRef (e.g. query  with @ViewChild(TemplateRef) template;)

Notice how *ng-template* 'SingleSelect' is captured into a `templateComponentVar` below:

*app.component.ts*

```
import { Component, ViewChild, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  @ViewChild('SingleSelect', { static: false }) templateComponentVar: TemplateRef<any>;
}
```

*app.component.html*

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="templateComponentVar"></ng-container>

<ng-template #SingleSelect>
  <p>Output from test template</p>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I needed